# Select country and automatic generate phone code in Ninja Form plugin - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phone-number, country-codes, ninja-forms

I have a Wordpress Ninja Form Plugin. I would like the code to auto generate country phone code (https://countrycode.org/) when selecting country in a list.